# pytube-Youtube function not initializing

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube

I have `pytube` installed, i am getting an error when i run it(I am using python 3.7), the problem seems to be with the `pytube` itself ,i am using exact code of tutorials for this module.

```
import pytube

link ='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0'
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
stream = yt.streams.first()
finished = stream.download()
print('Download is complete')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\automate the boring stuff\youtubetry.py", line 6, in <module>
    yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
  File "C:\Users\diodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.prefetch_init()


[Finished in 6.0s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue last week. Since I'm on Ubuntu, what worked for me was navigating to:

```
/home/<username>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytube
```

and adding

```
r'\bc\s*&&\s*d\.set\([^,]+,.*?\((?P<sig>[a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\(\(0\s*,\s*window.decodeURIComponent'
```

to the list of patterns in the `get_initial_function_name()` function in `cipher.py`. The error was further discussed in [this Github thread](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/312).

Comment: @eyllanesc kind of work it looks,`.js` for All youtube 'Vevo' videos has changed,strangely other than Vevo still some work some don't.

Comment: @timmy I have not written the answer, just edit it to make it look better